# stdarg.h and char paraments

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
void a_simple_func_with_variable_argument(int, ...);
void a_simple_func_with_variable_argument(int start, ...) {
  va_list pa;
  char ch;
  va_start(pa, start);
  while(ch = va_arg(pa, char)) {
    printf("%c, ", ch);
  }
  printf("End\n");
  va_end(pa);
}
...
//call the func above in somewhere 
  a_simple_func_with_variable_argument(1, 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0');
```

It failed after compiled by gcc, what do i missing?

Comment: Are you missing `stdarg.h`? What does the compiler tells you is missing?

Comment: va_arg takes two args...

Comment: my mistake, already fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with `char`; it's automatically promoted to `int` in a variadic function.  You will need to pass `int` as the second arg to `va_arg`.

Comment: I hate so foolish me.. Thank you guy:)

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your example (after fixing va_arg(pa, char)), the compiler (gcc 4.6) tells me

> a.c: In function 'a_simple_func_with_variable_argument':
>   a.c:8:14: warning: 'char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' [enabled by default]
>   a.c:8:14: note: (so you should pass 'int' not 'char' to 'va_arg')
>   a.c:8:14: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort

So no surprise here.

Comment: First come first served. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
int func(char a, char b, char c) /* DEMONSTRATION that char on stack is promoted to int !!!
                                    note: this promotion is NOT integer promotion of literals, but promotion during handling of the stack. don't confuse the two */
{
  const char *p = &a;
  printf("a=%d\n"
         "b=%d\n"
         "c=%d\n", *p, p[-(int)sizeof(int)], p[-(int)sizeof(int) * 2]); // don't do this. might probably work on x86 with gcc (but again: don't do this)
}
```

The message is `va_arg(ap, char)` and `va_arg(ap, short)` is wrong.
Use `va_arg(ap, int)` instead: it will handle arguments of type int and "smaller" type (short, char).

See also http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html
Quote: " Take care here to avoid problems which could be caused by arithmetic conversions. Use of char or short as the second argument to va_arg is invariably an error: these types always promote up to one of signed int or unsigned int, and float converts to double."